# Calling a list from one method to another in the same class in Python

Tags: python, list, class, methods, self

I am trying to call a list form init function to a method in the same class.

```
class department():
    def __init__(self,d_name,e_list):
        self.d_name=d_name
        self.e_list=e_list
    def calsal(self,bonus,designation):
        count=0
        for i in self.e_list:
            if e_list[i].employee_name.lower()==designation.lower():
                salary.update_salary(bonus)
                print(e_list[i].employee_id)
                print(e_list[i].employee_name)
                print(e_list[i].designation)
                print(e_list[i].salary)
                count=1
        if count==0:
            print('Employee Not Found')
```

But I am getting this error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:/Users/aditya/Desktop/1.py", line 39, in 
> dep.calsal(bonus,designation)
> File "C:/Users/aditya/Desktop/1.py", line 18, in calsal
> if e_list[i].employee_name.lower()==designation.lower():
> NameError: name 'e_list' is not defined

I have used the self keyword. How to rectify this

Comment: *"I have used the self keyword."*  -- No, you haven't. Read your code properly ;-)

Comment: By the way, `self` [isn't a keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-word-self).

Comment: `self.e_list[i]` will fail, because iterating over `e_list` doesn't produce indices, it produces the members of the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, as indicated by the error you posted, there is no self for the e_list throwing the error. You need to use `self.e_list` everytime you want to reference that specific list inside your instance.

Secondly, your variable `i` is not a number, but an employee, so you should name it accordingly. That will also reveal why `e_list[i]` will give you an index error.

```py
    def calsal(self,bonus,designation):
        count=0
        for employee in self.e_list:
            if employee.employee_name.lower()==designation.lower():
                employee.salary.update_salary(bonus)
                print(employee.employee_id)
                print(employee.employee_name)
                print(employee.designation)
                print(employee.salary)
                count=1
        if count==0:
            print('Employee Not Found')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. "employee.salary.update_salary(bonus)" In this statement update_salary is a method from another class that takes 'bonus' as an argument. It updates the value 'salary'. How to call it?

Comment: I got this an AttributeError saying that int object salary doesn't have the attribute update_salary. I changed the update_salary method to take two arguments, salary and bonus, and changed the statement to "employee.salary=Employee.update_salary(employee.salary,bonus)". Now it is working fine. Just wondering is there any other way to do this without passing salary as an argument?

Comment: You should be able to access salary from the `update_salary` function with `self.salary`